# how to connect to webrick from different computer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, webrick

This question has been asked a few times before on stack overflow and I've tried the various recommendations but still can't get it working.

I'm on OSX 10.11, home wifi network, using Chrome. If I boot webrick with the following:

```
rails server -b 0.0.0.0
```

The server starts and I can access my app via http://0.0.0.0:3000/ on the same computer but from a different computer (also an up-to-date OSX on the same wifi network) I get an ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

whatismyip.com says my IP is 76.14.66.137. When I try any of the following

```
rails s -b 76.14.66.137
rails s -b 76.14.66.137 -p 80
rails s -b 76.14.66.137 -p 3000
rails s -b 76.14.66.137 -p 3002
```

I get the same error every time: Can't assign requested address - bind(2) for 76.14.66.137:80 (Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL)

Is there an OSX setting that I may need to change? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0.0.0.0` means to listen all network interfaces.

https://www.whatismyip.com/ gives you the router's external IP. This is not the IP you would use to connect to your local server with a separate local machine. You need to get your machine's real, internal IP address. (On OSX this is easy, just open Network Preferences and your internal IP is listed at the top under "Status: Connected". You can also find the IP by logging into your router adminstration.) Let's say your machine running the rails server has an internal IP of 191.166.0.100.

So you would start your local server with 0.0.0.0 ip address on machine A. Then on machine B you would connect to http://191.166.0.100:3000.. machine A's interal IP. Then you will get response from your rails app. If not then you need to check out server firewall settings and router settings.

Comment: I used rails server -b 0.0.0.0 to start the server, then tried to connect with my ip on the other computer: http://76.14.66.137:3000. Still doesn't work. I don't know what firewall settings and/or router settings would be causing the problem. Is there something in particular I should be looking for, or could google for?

Comment: if you trying to connect to webrick from internet then you need to enable port forwarding in your router. You can find how to do it in google with search query like '(router-model) port forwarding' or '(router-model) access intranet from internet'

Comment: thanks for your help, your last comment led me to figure out that I was using my public router IP and not my computer's own internal IP to boot webrick. Pretty silly, I know, just goes to show how easy it is to get tripped up with this stuff when you don't know anything about this server/network stuff.

Comment: you basically said this in your original answer but it wasn't clear to me. I tried editing your answer to make it a little more clear, once the edit is posted I'll accept it.

Comment: hopefully the edit is not too extensive to be accepted